# Problems displaying aspx pages in different folder than master page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a site master page which uses some JQuery scripts, when my site accesses anything that is in my Account folder, the page loads but not without an error message as well as a messed up master page. It works fine if I pull the page out from the Account folder. Trying the entire day to figure this out but to no avail. Appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: Define "an error message" and "a messed up master page."  We need actual information about the problem.

Comment: Upon clicking to access any page in the Account page, a 'Webpage Error' popsup with the error "Do you want to debug this webpage? This webpage contains errors that might prevent it from displaying or working correctly. Below is a error textbox with :
Line:76
Error: '$' is undefined

Comment: You're still going to have to do some basic debugging here, since we can't see your code (specifically line 76).  It sounds like it's a JavaScript error.  You can use a debugger like FireBug to step through the JavaScript and see what the state of the objects are and what code is throwing the error.  **Edit:** Based on the error message, it sounds like the code is trying to use jQuery before the jQuery library has been loaded.

Comment: I think it is a relative link problem when you have master page in one place, and content page in folder or somewhere else (not same path)
I've posted my solution I use for this

Comment: Here is the answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025920/using-jquery-in-a-subfolder-when-the-masterpage-is-in-the-root-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be security issue

First ensure that you added proper realtive path of the javascript file in you file...

and

Read this : [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

allow an anonymous user to gain access the Account.aspx page.
Copy

```
<configuration>
   <location path="~/Users>
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll be to do with your links to CSS and JavaScript. Ensure your add "../" to go up a level in folder structure.

Comment: This will ruin every page that uses the master page outside that folder

Comment: The pages outside doesn't seem to get affected.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really have sufficient information to provide a definitive answer here - for instance, what do you mean by 'an error message'? What is the source? How is it displayed? and, most importantly, what does it say? What happens if you remove use of jQuery, does the page display and function as expected?

That aside, to account for a 'messed up MasterPage', I would assume that your Account folder has restricted access via `authorization` section of the web.config. This can be adjusted to allow access to certain resources; in the `authorization` section, you may have something like this:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

The above will lock out access to all files that fall within the path that this is within scope of. Naturally your login page will be accessible, but maybe not resources such as CSS files and images - to allow these to be accessed by users not yet authenticated you can configure a custom `location`, as such:

```
<location path="pathToResources">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, ASP.NET interprets relative links from the "viewpoint" of the page, so if the page is in folder, your master page relative links will not work anymore.

Here is the solution that I use, wrap your head content in a custom control which will do the rebase:

```
<asp_custom:RebasingContainer ID="mainRebase" runat="server">
</asp_custom:RebasingContainer>
```

for  and  use runat=server and use them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/reset.css"/>
```

Note the "~" which is ASP.NET "go from root" path.

For controls, use this:

```
[ControlBuilder(typeof(RebasingContainerBuilder)),
  Designer("System.Web.UI.Design.ControlDesigner, System.Design, " +
  "Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"),
  ConstructorNeedsTag(false)]
public class RebasingContainer : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public RebasingContainer()
    {

    }

    protected override void RenderBeginTag(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {  /*doesn't render it's own tag*/ }

    protected override void RenderEndTag(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {/*doesn't render it's own tag*/}
}
```

The control uses following control builder:

```
public class RebasingContainerBuilder : ControlBuilder
{
    public override bool AllowWhitespaceLiterals()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override Type GetChildControlType(string tagName, System.Collections.IDictionary attribs)
    {
        if (string.Equals(tagName, "link", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return typeof(HtmlLink);
        }

        if (string.Equals(tagName, "script", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && attribs.Contains("src"))
        {
            //only rebase script tags that have a src attribute!
            return typeof(HtmlScript);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Where the script is:

```
public class HtmlScript : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public HtmlScript() : base("script") { }

    public HtmlScript(string tag) : base(tag) { }

    public string Src
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Attributes["src"];
        }
        set
        {
            this.Attributes["src"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Src = ResolveClientUrl(Src);
        base.RenderAttributes(writer);
    }
}
```

Register your customer rebase control in web.config and you are ready to go. For example:

```
<add assembly="__code" namespace="CustomControls" tagPrefix="asp_custom" />
```

if you use AppCode folder.

This solution will give you runtime as well as design time support for separated master and simple web pages.

Comment: A simple `/` prefix to CSS links go from root anyway, no need to invoke .NET to expand the path.

Comment: Thanks Mr Disappointment, it's the omission of / prefix before the CSS and JS file links causing the problem!

Comment: @Mr Disappointment that works only if resource is in site root, which isn't true for lots of websites. If you have localhost/TestSite/Folder1/default.aspx, where TestSite is the name of your site, and master in root, content using that master in Folder1 -> that will not work.

Comment: @Denis: No, it works _from_ the root, so things can be in sub-folders, such that: `/resources/resource1.css`, where the first `/` represents the root.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain right - by site root I meant that site adress isn't in domain "root" like having localhost/TestSite where TestSite is the name of the Virtual Directory. In this case this will not work, because /resources/resource1.css will give localhost/resources/resource1.css instead of localhost/TestSite/resources/resource1.css

Comment: @Denis: You misunderstand. If your site is in a virtual directory then you _would_ need to add that to your relative path, such that: `/vdir/resources/resource1.css`. My original comment still stands - this is overkill.

Comment: and if I deploy and change the vdir to vdir2, am I to change every relative path in my app?

Comment: @Denis: Given that it's a folder, then yes, just like you would need to change the path for _any_ folder (such as the `resources` folder itself) that undergoes a name change - there is nothing out of the ordinary here.

Comment: If in my solution I have css folder with stylesheets, I want to write ~/css/style.css, not /mydeploymentvirtualdirectory/css/style.css. If you prefer your way, and don't see a problem there, that is your choice

Answer (score 1):

simply use this:

putting / before js do the trick.

`<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Referenced from here :
[Using JQuery in a Subfolder When the MasterPage is in the Root Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025920/using-jquery-in-a-subfolder-when-the-masterpage-is-in-the-root-folder)

Answer (score 0):

When you have javascript or jQuery in a subfolder and pages in the root folder with some in a subfolder, do this: add two links for each javascript file in your masterpage:

eg:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How it works: Pages in the subfolders will be referenced to the link with `../`, i.e

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Pages in root folder will be referenced to the link without `../`, i.e

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Tip: If you can't get one folder working or the other, play with the: `~/`, `/`, `../`, and `./` one will reference it for you.